# Cryptic python error 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__'. Why am I getting this?

Tags: class, python-2.7, object, types, instantiation

I really wish I could be more specific here but I have read through related questions and none of them seem to relate to the issue that I am experiencing here and I have no understanding of the issue i am experiencing. This is for a homework assignment so I am hesitant to put up all my code for the program, here is a stripped down version. Compile this and you will see the issue.

```
import copy

class Ordering:

    def __init__(self, tuples):

        self.pairs = copy.deepcopy(tuples)
        self.sorted = []
        self.unsorted = []

        for x in self.pairs:
            self.addUnsorted(left(x))
            self.addUnsorted(right(x))

    def addUnsorted(self, item):

        isPresent = False

        for x in self.unsorted:
            if x == item:
                isPresent = True

        if isPresent == False:
            self.unsorted.append(left(item))
```

Here I have created a class, Ordering, that takes a list of the form [('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'A')] (where a must come before b, c must come before b, etc.) and is supposed to return it in partial ordered form. I am working on debugging my code to see if it works correctly but I have not been able to yet because of the error message I get back.

When I input the follwing in my terminal:

```
print Ordering[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'A')]
```

I get back the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in (module) Type Error: 'classobj' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Why is this?!

Comment: You may have noticed, that your demo-code uses a functions  `left()`, `right()` that are not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an element of a list, use square brackets.  To instantiate a class, use parens.

In other words, do not use:

```
print Ordering[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'A')]
```

Use:

```
print Ordering((('A', 'B'), ('C', 'B'), ('D', 'A')))
```

This will generate another error from deeper in the code but, since this is a homework assignment, I will let you think about that one a bit.

#### How to use `__getitem__`:

As a minimal example, here is a class that returns squares via `__getitem__`:

```
class HasItems(object):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key**2
```

In operation, it looks like this:

```
>>> a = HasItems()
>>> a[4]
16
```

Note the square brackets.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My error was that I forgot the parenthesis to enclose my argument to the class. Thanks for the example of getitem as well, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

### Answer to "Why is this?"

Your demo-code is not complete ( ref. comment above ), however the issue with **`.__getitem__`** method is clearly related with a statement to `print` an object ( which due to other reasons did fail to respond to a request to answer to a called `.__getitem__` method ) rather than the Class itself.

```
>>> aList = [ ('A','B'), ('C','D'), ('E','F')]       # the stated format of input
>>> aList                                            # validated to be a list
[('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')]
>>> type( aList )                                    # cross-validated
<type 'list'>
>>> for x in aList:                                  # iterator over members
...     print x, type(  x )                          # show value and type
...     left( x )                                    # request as in demo-code
...
('A', 'B') <type 'tuple'>
Traceback (most recent call last):                   <<< demo-code does not have it
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
NameError: name 'left' is not defined


>>> dir( Ordering )                                  # .__getitem__ method missing
[ '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'addUnsorted']


>>> dir( aList[0] )                                  # .__getitem__ method present
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__',
 '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__',
 '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__',
 '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__',
 'count', 'index']
```